# Pandas: Calculate remaining time in grouping

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a requirement to sort a table by date starting from the oldest. Total field is created by grouping `name` and `kind` fields and applying sum. Now for each row I need to calculate the remaining time in the same `name-kind` grouping.

The csv looks like that:

```
date       name kind duration total remaining
1-1-2017   a    1    10       100   ? should be 90
2-1-2017   b    1    5        35    ? should be 30
3-1-2017   a    2    3        50    ? should be 47
4-1-2017   b    2    1        25    ? should be 24
5-1-2017   a    1    8        100   ? should be 82
6-1-2017   b    1    2        35    ? should be 33
7-1-2017   a    2    3        50    ? should be 44
8-1-2017   b    2    6        25    ? should be 18
...
```

My question is how do I calculate the remaining value while having the `DataFrame` grouped by `name` and `kind`?

My initial approach was to shift the column and add the values from duration to each other like that:

```
df['temp'] = df.groupby(['name', 'kind'])['duration'].apply(lambda x: x.shift() + x)
```

and then:

```
df['duration'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['total'] - x['temp'], axis=1)
```

But it did not work as expected.

Is there a clean way to do it, or using the `iloc, ix, loc` somehow is the way to go?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
df["cumsum"] = df.groupby(['name', 'kind'])["duration"].cumsum()
df["remaining"] = df["total"] - df["cumsum"]
```

Being careful with resetting the index maybe.